# Replicate data of one field into new index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an existing index which has an unindexed field that holds sentences.

```
"sentence" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "index" : false
          }
```

Now I need to have these fields indexed as I need to run `match` queries on these sentences. I do not need any other data than this specific field. Hence I was looking for some way to index this field into a new index and then query.
Is there some better way out or at the worst how do I achieve what I have thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the settings or mappings for an index, you must create a new index with the new settings and mappings, then copy the documents from the original index to the new index. Elasticsearch provides the [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to copy documents from one index to another index:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "original_twitter"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter"
  }
}
```